# Migrating Hyper-V storage server to another VM in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v, windows-storage-server

Here at work we have a storage server (windows server 2003) VM in Hyper-V. We recently installed a new VM in Hyper-V with server 2012 R2 and would like to migrate our storage server to this new VM. We have a a virtual HD allocated to the 2003 server with all of our shares. Would the following steps work for migrating between VMs?:

> Copy Volume registry info from 2003 Storage Server
>
> Shutdown 2003 Storage Server
>
> Allocate the VHD to the new VM (2012 R2)
>
> Import the Registry info to retain all shares and permissions
>
> Update the IP on the new VM to match the old VM.
>
> Done....

Does this work or should I approach it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, i would use Migration tools that are included in Windows Server 2012 R2. It will migrate everything (shares, permissions, data...) and it's a full supported way to migrate from Windows Server 2003 to a newest operating system. Last but not least, it's very simple to use it.

Basically the process will be the following :
- Install a new Windows Server 2012 R2 VM with all needed VHDs
- Install File Role and Services in the new WS2012R2 VM
- Install the Server Migration Tools on destination Server
- Open TCP and UDP port 7000 and make sure that it is not in use by other applications. This port is used by Send-SmigServerData and Receive-SmigServerData to establish a data transfer connection.
- Verify that the destination path has sufficient disk space to migrate the data
- Use the same drive letters for the destination server volumes as for the source server. This is required, because FSRM migration requires the drive letter to remain the same.
- Install migration tool on source server and execute it

All detailled step by step operations are here :
File and Storage Services: Prepare to Migrate
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479284%28v=ws.11%29.aspx
File and Storage Services: Migrate the File and Storage Services Role
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479292%28v=ws.11%29.aspx